# Multiple javascript 'click to enable' script

Tags: javascript

I have 2 divs on my page that are set to only be visible once a particular radio button is selected. The first one was fine but as soon as I added the other, the first one no longer worked. I am in a situation now where I can only get one to work at a time. I'm assuming it must be down to the way I am writing the scripts, there must be something missing that tells both to work and not just one or the other.

The 2 divs that appear on clicking the radio button are: 'nterms' and 'liabilityinsur'. I initally had this in 2 seperate scripts(so a close script tag then an open one for the next) but that didn't make any difference.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9NQHK/)

Here is the javascript

```
<script>
    function unCheck(checkedObj)
    {   
        switch (checkedObj)
        {   case "individual":
               document.getElementById("process").tscs.checked=false;
               document.getElementById("nterms").style.display="block";
               break;

            case "agencyconsultant":
               document.getElementById("process").tscs.checked=true;
               document.getElementById("nterms").style.display="none";
               break;

            case "friendrelative":
               document.getElementById("process").tscs.checked=true;
               document.getElementById("nterms").style.display="none";
               break;
        }
    }

    function unCheck(checkedObj)
    {   
        switch (checkedObj)
        {   case "ownliabinsurance":
              document.getElementById("process").tscs.checked=false;
      document.getElementById("liabilityinsur").style.display="block";
              break;

            case "noliabinsurance":
              document.getElementById("process").tscs.checked=true;
      document.getElementById("liabilityinsur").style.display="none";
              break;
         }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net so we can see the html without having to do so ourselves - also your second script will replace your first unless you rename one of them. That is how JS works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second script will replace your first unless you rename one of them. That is how JS works

Also your tscs code is wrong. The checkbox is `document.getElementById("tscs")`

I decided when I now saw your html to change it to this:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/YN22a/)

Change the 3 *Filling in as* radios to `onclick="unCheckAs(this)` as in

`<input type="radio" id="individual" name="req_FilledInBy" value="Individual"  onClick="unCheckAs(this);" <?php .... ?>  />`

and the *Have insurance* radios to `onclick="unCheckIns(this)` as in

`<input type="radio" id="ownliabinsurance" name="req_OwnLiabilityInsurance" value="ownliabinsurance"  onClick="unCheckIns(this);" <?php .... ?>  />`

```
function unCheckAs(rad) {   
  var radID = rad.id;
  var individual = radID=="individual";
  document.getElementById("tscs").checked=!individual;
  document.getElementById("nterms").style.display=(individual)?"block":"none";
}

function unCheckIns(rad) {   
  var radID = rad.id;
  var own = radID=="ownliabinsurance";
  document.getElementById("liabilityinsur").style.display=(own)?"block":"none"    
}
```

Comment: I just replaced what I had with your answer here but then neither of the scripts work.

Comment: You did have to think a little too. I just saw your fiddle but it is PHP so I would have to remove the php to test my code. Also I use (this) instead of (this.id) - see update

Comment: I should have thought, sorry! Got numerous things on at once so bare with me... So where you say change the onclick="unCheck(this.id to onclick="unCheck(this), where do I change this? There is no onclick in my code or yours?

Comment: I'm sorry but you will have to bare with me, which part relates to the 'Filling in as radios'?

Comment: Have you changed any of my html too as if I change the scripts to yours I still get neother script working.

Comment: Yes, i see what you mean with that. That shouldn't happen. However it is not likely that someone will check the 'I agree to the terms' box then uncheck it then go back to the liability box so don't think that's anything to worry about. Unless you can think of an obvious answer to fix this?

Comment: The only thing needed to show the t and c's box is when 'individual' is selected.

Comment: I would consider changing the names to `function showTscs` and `function showLiabilityInsurance` since they have less to do with unchecking than with showing now

Comment: Ok, all sorted and thanks for the help. Since doing this though, the form will no longer submit. if I put the script back to as it was, it submits fine. Any idea if there is anything I should be looking for? When I submit the form, it just refreshes the page now

Comment: I shall have a look now but if you don't mind haveing a look, the link is http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/onlineforms/Payco-Tech-Registration.asp

Comment: I am aware of these issues and I don't even use t=most of those scripts anymore, they just need clearing down. Having said that, it has submitted without an issue until this morning? I have other forms on other pages with the same errors that submit fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, all I know is this submits fine if I revert back to my previous scripts so a bit confused now.

Comment: I found the error, I have some code that says 'If request("submit") = "Register with Payco Tech" then' but I had the submit code as "Register with payco Tech" (lower case p) so fixed that now :)

Comment: The question now is how to make it also work on mobile.... any ideas on that? The code you have given me doesn't work for multiple instances ie. desktop/mobile etc.

Comment: That is because you have duplicate IDs for tscs. You need to change one (and have a function m_unCheckAs for example) or use class or name for the tscs checkbox and then loop over both.

Comment: This is getting close to custom coding. I normally charge for that :)

Comment: Hi, I do agree and think I shouldn't be asking any more questions :) I really would like to learn this myself anyway so will take your advice on the duplicate id's and try to resolve myself. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Could you just explain why 2 of the functions miss one line that the first one does? The first one that makes the T&C's appear has this line which the others don't 'var individual = radID=="individual";'

Comment: I see id="tscs" twice in that fiddle

Comment: The individual and m_individual are correct in your fork of the fiddle

Comment: Where do you see tscs twice? The javascript references tscs and m_tscs

Comment: In the fiddle you have tscs in both sets of divs. just search for id="tscs"

Comment: I missed that, thanks for the heads up. i'm confused now though as this all looks correct now? http://jsfiddle.net/YN22a/9/

Comment: No. <div id="nterms" style="display: none;"> in themobile part needs to be mterms

Comment: And I needed to change 'individual' to 'm_individual'. Got it working now :)

Comment: And the other radios also needed m_ and nterm to mterm. Please see this version and remember to have unique ID... http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/a2VTZ/

Comment: Yes I changed the n and mterms too so it;s great now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both your functions have the same name.
This means the 2nd one will replace the 1st

Comment: Darn, was it that obvious?? so is the name that needs changing 'checkedObj'?